# Api POST from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, post

I want to post an object using an API call. I'm getting the data using the following code in my codebehind

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

 client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JUri"]);
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


 HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/receipt/" + jID).Result;
 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {}
```

I would like to know there is any code equivalent to POST for this.

Comment: Why dont you define a model for Amount and MailID?

Comment: There is too many parameters and that model-as-parameter didnt work. so i passed it as separate strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POST using Form:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JUri"]);

var postData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Key1", "Value1"));
postData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Key2 ", "Value2"));

HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);
var response = client.PostAsync("api/receipt/" + jID, content)
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{}
```

POST using JSON, assume you have Dto class:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var dto = new Dto {Pro1 = "abc"};

var reponse = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/receipt/" + jID, dto).Result;

if (reponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{}
```

Comment: For the POST using JSON, do i need to set the postData as key value pairs?

Comment: @NewBie: No, just pass your object into method

Comment: I tried your code and it hhelped to call my POST method but my parameters are not getting assigned to the post method's parameters.

Comment: Omg... My bad.... Yours works perfectly. It was some issue with my string manipulation. Thanx a ton for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The best way for you is to use a third-party library, like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)
The simple way to post something to your api via RestSharp will look like that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using RestSharp;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class SimpleConnector
    {
        private CookieContainer _cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        private RestClient client = new RestClient();
        public string TwitterAuthenticate(string user, string pass)
        {
            client.CookieContainer = _cookieJar;
            //RestClient client = new RestClient("https://twitter.com");
            IRestRequest request = new RestRequest("https://twitter.com/", Method.GET);
            client.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0";
            client.AddDefaultHeader("Accept", "*/*");
            //request.AddParameter("name", "value"); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
            //request.AddUrlSegment("id", "123"); // replaces matching token in request.Resource

            // easily add HTTP Headers
            //request.AddHeader("header", "value");

            // add files to upload (works with compatible verbs)

            // execute the request
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;
            Match m = Regex.Match(content, @"name=""authenticity_token""\s*value=""(.*?)"">");
            string authenticity_token = m.Groups[1].Value;
            request = new RestRequest("https://twitter.com/sessions", Method.POST);
            request.AddParameter("session[username_or_email]", user);
            request.AddParameter("session[password]", pass);
            request.AddParameter("return_to_ssl", "true");
            request.AddParameter("scribe_log", "");
            request.AddParameter("redirect_after_login", "/");
            request.AddParameter("authenticity_token", authenticity_token);
            response = client.Execute(request);
            content = response.Content;
            return content;
        }
```

Comment: Isn't there anything that i can directly use.. without a third party library? Something plain?

Comment: You can use HttpWebRequest with HttpWebRequest.Method like POST, than u have to write your posted content to stream and count it's length, then - send it to server

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this way:

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

 client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JUri"]);
```

You could either use one of these methods as given below as per your requirement:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.PostAsJsonAsync();
```

OR

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.PostAsXmlAsync();
```

OR

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.PostAsync();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: where can i pass the post data here? i have and object and how can send it as the post data?